# python openCV video source dialog with image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a program that takes an image from your webcam but every time i run it, a dialog box pops up asking for a video source, no matter what i press, it doesn't write the image

```
import cv2

camera_port = 0

ramp_frames = 30
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def get_image():

 retval, im = camera.read()
 return im

for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
 temp = get_image()

camera_capture = get_image()
file_ = "test_image.png"

cv2.imwrite(file_, camera_capture)
camera.release()
del(camera)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutting down my computer, waiting 30 seconds and turning it back on seemed to fix the problem